# Can/should I install .deb files under MacPorts using dpkg

Tags: python, macports, dpkg

I'm installing [otrfileconverter](https://github.com/guardianproject/otrfileconverter) from the [Guardian Project](https://guardianproject.info/) which depends upon the python modules potr and pyjavaproperties, which exist under Fink but not MacPorts.

I could do this all manually but I'd rather contribute instructions for installing under MacPorts.  These packages don't exist under Debian either, but can be easily added using the [Guardian Project PPA](https://launchpad.net/~guardianproject/+archive/ppa).

I should obviously just write the MacPorts Portfile's for these two packages to contribute to MacPorts, but I started wondering ..

Does anyone use MacPort's [dpkg](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=dpkg) port for managing Debian packages under MacPorts?  Could I produce instructions that simply used `dpkg`?

Just curious what `dpkg` gets used for under MacPorts really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These Debian/Ubuntu .deb packages contain compiled binaries and libraries, which may be linked to other libraries provided by these systems. You can't expect them to run on any other system than exactly the one it was made for. In particular, you cannot use Linux binaries on a Mac OS X system.

Your best option is to write the missing Portfiles. The [MacPorts Guide](http://guide.macports.org/#development) gives an introduction to writing Portfiles.

The dpkg port in MacPorts exists for experimentation purposes only, for extraction of .deb packages and the like. Similar, there are also ports for rpm, yum and apt. All of them are not used by MacPorts itself.